# User input of program feature request in TFS2010

Tags: tfs, user-stories

Is there any way that users can enter feature requests, so that they will appear in TFS2010?

We would like to keep an overview of all incoming requests and only create our own `User Stories` after verifying these requests.

Comment: An important consideration is that there *may* be licensing repurcussions in this configuration.  Depending on how this is set up and who is accessing it, external users creating requests *may* require a TFS CAL and you may wish to research the licensing further.

Comment: Good remark Edward! I need to verify this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, if I read this correctly, you 'd like to generate a new Work Item type named "Feature" or similar. A very nice post on that can be found [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=755).

Then you would like customers to remotely access your TFS, so they can generate/view your "Features". See [Work Item Only Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx) for that. Another presentation on how to set this up, is to be found [here](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/07/14/quick-and-easy-setup-for-ldquowork-item-only-viewrdquo-web-users-in-tfs-2010), where in the comments OP writes:

> The great thing we find at my work, is that you can create a
>   linked worked item from a client submitted bug, and they cannot see
>   the work item and the internal chatter inside the work item. This
>   works out great

This is a very nice bonus.

Comment: Pantelif this looks promising! I'll have some reading to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Work Item Read Only view is the perfect tool for you. It is just TFS Web Access, but the users are placed in the Work Item Only security group: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx